# MonoTouch does not support dynamic proxy code generation

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wsdl

I've read a lot of articles about adding SOAP WSDL into Xamarin.ios project (mainly overriding a ChannelFactory class) but I cannot get my head to wrap around it.

I have 10+k lines of autogenerated Connected Service that works perfectly on android but it's throwing a:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
  Message=MonoTouch does not support dynamic proxy code generation. Override this method or its caller to return specific client proxy instance
```

on iOS.

Is there some simple guide to follow on how-to-set-up-non-dynamic-proxy-code-generation on iOS? 
I'm starting to get desperate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've opted out of doing SOAP and went with RESTfull.
No idea if SOAP is even possible in iOS now, so if there is an option to go with REST do it.

Comment: How have you managed it to go restful? Have you converted hand to hand every soap call with a rest one?

Comment: The vendor that we used for this application (their APIs) does have an REST version.
The client and the management at that (starting) point wanted to do everything via SOAP, but we had to switch to REST for iOS, even thou Android has been done via SOAP at the start.